# BJT low frequency analysis

Tags: bjt, cutoff-frequency

I have a little bit of confusion on how the textbook author is determining the low frequency cutoffs for the 3 high pass filter components of this circuit:

[image]

For the capacitor Cs, he finds Zi which is after the capacitor, while treating Ce as a short. That makes sense because it would create the equivalent of a simple RC circuit and you can do your normal RC frequency analysis 1/(2*pi* Zi* Cs). Since Ce was shorted to ground, RE is shorted as well.

For the capacitor Ce, he finds the Thevenin resistance looking into the opened capacitor Ce, while also opening the capacitor Cs. Not to mention that he doesn't even look at the components that are connected to the collector...

Why is it when we are focused on the effects of capacitor Cs, we short capacitor Ce, and while we are focused on the effects of capacitor Ce, we open capacitor Cs?

This is from Boylestad Electronics Devices and Circuit Theory 11th Edition. This shows what he Cs, and it doesn't include the resistor RE, implying that Ce has been shorted. Note that little re is the base to emitter model resistors (approximated 26mV/IE) :

[image]

And this is what he does for capacitor Ce, and it implies that the Capacitor Cs is opened (for thevenin resistance, the voltage source would be shorted, and thus R1 and R2 would be shorted if not for the opening of Cs):

[image]

Comment: CE or Ce. Your choices imply collector emitter or capacitor \$C_E\$. You need to be precise.

Comment: @Andyaka Seconded. I also don’t understand what the text you are referring to is doing. The Thevenin theorem is applied presumably between a junction and the ground. It is not clear at which junction it is applied. Usually this is done at the base. You need to add more information.

Comment: Okay I changed all to Ce.

Comment: Added more details

Comment: The author is cheating and he knows the outcomes. In all of these cases, you should treat the remaining capacitor as short circuits. This is also a major simplifying assumption. But this is how it is done.

Comment: @SittinHawk I know the circuit is *in a book*. It's never used in practice, isolated. And there're good reasons for that. So this is a *don't-use-without-global-NFB-and-only-as-one-section-among-many* circuit, grabbed up and taken into an isolation where it isn't used. Just FYI. G36 is right in saying that the emitter capacitor is usually assumed to have "low enough impedance, in the context" that it can be treated as a direct short. But it actually almost always has enough impedance in this circuit to be important -- it rarely is big enough, in short. Also, it affects phase. But oh well.

Comment: @SittinHawk So, I'm sitting here wondering what exactly you'd like to know? Are you really looking to be convinced of something, in particular? Or looking to have a more sweeping, inclusive, thorough, and more fully analytical answer from which a simplified version that matches the book can be extracted through the use of acceptable "assume this away" notes? Or?

Comment: As for what I'm looking for: I like the approach he is taking because it doesn't involve generating a small signal AC model, and deriving a giant transfer function in the S-domain with all capacitors simultaneously. I get that this is probably a "close enough" approximation method and I'm fine with that. I'd like to know the rules of doing this method. I can just blindly memorize what he has done for this particular circuit, but the minute I face a different circuit with a capacitor in a different location, I'm won't be confident that I can derive a similar result.

Comment: The reason the author does not include the base capacitor is because there is an AC source on the other side. Keep in mind that during AC analysis only the DC sources are shorted, as per the superposition theorem. Then you have two steps. Firstly, input to system (9.26). Secondly, system to Ce (9.29). However I would caution you that this is a rather unconventional approach. It is not that difficult to derive the total transfer function using the pi model. Have a look through [this](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/electronics-lab-5fr).

Comment: @SittinHawk Okay. So you get the approach. But it looks like a one-off to you and while you can memorize it you don't feel you could have created the idea on your own, so you are worried. There's no magic answer. As you develop more ways of seeing things (upside down, sideways, etc), you'll get better at it. I'm still learning new ways to see things using old familiar ideas applied to old familiar circuits that I hadn't just seen that way, before. When that happens, I can flip from one view to another instantly and I think better. So it never ends.

Comment: @SittinHawk There is a tiny dynamic resistance (or, if you prefer, the Boltzmann thermal voltage divided by the instantaneous emitter current) that kind of "hangs" at the very tip of the emitter. This comes from implicit differentiation of the Shockley equation used in the simplified, active mode portion of the Ebers-Moll level 1 model. It's something you should definitely memorize. There's also the Early Effect (basewidth modulation), which shows up in the level 3 Ebers-Moll model -- also worth memorizing.

Comment: This textbook did not do it quite right. It  may have other characteristics that make it an appropriate introductory circuits textbook. For a better understanding of this technique Google “short circuit time constant method”